# Reporting tool which print the control which we pass on that

Tags: c#, mysql, reporting

What is the best reporting tool other than crystal  report using with c# and mysql because crystal report has to be downloaded in user machine ? So what is the other alternative of the crystal report for using c# with mysql and should be less in size and user will not have to need to download more.And it should be with good features. (All open source and with paying charge.)

EDIT: I have need of printing only control on the form dynamically, like if user want to print third party control then also it should be printed, but it should not be printed like image of the treeview like if user wants to print the treeview on the window form but treeview is collapsed by user so here if user prints this treeview then it should not be printed collapsed treeview and but it should be printed whole the treeview(expanded).

Answer (score 0):

Not a reporting tool at all, but if you're most interested with simply having a PDF output I recommend [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).  You can then fill the report with place holders to be replaced with variables as you would any software - prior to the user downloading it.

Not the best method I agree, but it all depends on what you're looking for.

Comment: @m.edondson, is it dynamic like how does it print ?

Comment: @Harikrishna - Yes it generates PDF files at runtime (so you can manipulate the data as you wish).  It will provide a PDF file for the user so they can go File -> Print.

Comment: @m.edmondson, And like if in the user interface with the tool if suppose there is treeview and it is totally collapsed then will it print whole the treeview perfectly even if it is collapsed that is it should not print as a view it should print whole treeview ?

Comment: @Harikrishna - Not sure what you mean there, it will print whatever is in the PDF

Comment: @m.edmondson,like if our comments below your answer will be more and will not be read at first glance and if you refresh this page then all the comments will be shouwn but if we print this page it should print all the comments even if all the comments are not viewed at a first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Two options for you to use

- SQL Reporting Services - this has a requirement that you install a Microsoft SQL server with SRS but your reports themselves can connect to other databases, including MySQL (via ODBC) and you can then use the ReportViewer component in your C# applications to render it. There is no additional downloads for the user as the processing happens server side, plus it is easy to embed into web apps, SharePoint etc...
- Visual Studio 2010 does ship with fantastic reporting controls which can use any data source. If you on 2008 you can use the out of band release of these same controls. In all cases these are just code so it's a few extra assemblies to deploy. You can see samples of these in: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart